# PHP color in calendar error undefined variable

Tags: javascript, php

The color can be insert and update to database, then changing the event's color in calendar. However, I cannot display color from database to the textbox and show undefined in **console.log** .But another data(title,perihal,time) can be show in the specified textbox using same way.

This is my html code (display data):

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPatient">Perihal:</label>
                <div class="field desc" id="modal_show_perihal">
                   <select class="form-control" id="perihal" name="perihal" placeholder="perihal" type="text" value="">
                <option value="#a">a</option>
                <option value="#b">b</option>
                <option value="#c">c</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPatient">Color:</label>
                <div class="field desc" id="modal_show_color">
                   <select class="form-control" id="color" name="color" placeholder="color" type="text" value="">
                <option value="#FF0000">Red</option>
                <option value="#800000">Maroon</option>
                <option value="#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </div><br>
```

This is javascript(for show data):

```
eventClick:  function(arg) {
             $('#modal_show > #title').val(arg.event.title);
             $('#modal_show > #eventID').val(arg.event.id);
             $('#modal_show_perihal > #perihal').val(arg.event.extendedProps.perihal);
             $('#modal_show_from > #mesyuarat_from_date').val(arg.event.extendedProps.mesyuarat_from_date);
             $('#modal_show_to > #mesyuarat_to_date').val(arg.event.extendedProps.mesyuarat_to_date);
             $('#modal_show_color > #color').val(arg.event.extendedProps.color);
             console.log(arg.event.extendedProps.color);
             $('#calendarModal').modal();
            },
            
      editable: true,
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>
    });
```

Comment: Do `console.log(arg.event)` see what its giving you .

Comment: e {_context: {…}, _def: {…}, _instance: {…}}     @Swati

Comment: where did you set `$myArray = [a,b,c]`?

Comment: $myArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $myArray[] = $row;
    }
}

Comment: can you show entire output ? or just check is there any `color` field in that output  .Also  , try like this `console.log(arg.event.color)` as well.

Comment: @Swati `console.log(arg.event.color)` also undefined. The entire output is long,haha

Comment: Okay after searching try : `console.log(arg.event._def.ui.backgroundColor)` .

Comment: @Swati  Oh yeah! It's work! Love you, thank for your help